# Do Bitcoins mined in a pool automatically transfer to your wallet?

Tags: mining-pools, guiminer

I've installed the GUIMiner app and the Multibit app.  I am in a mining pool, and I have about 17 shares thus far. Do the Bitcoins transfer to my MultBit wallet automatically or do I need to do it manually?

Comment: This probably depends on the policies of your pool; since you don't say what it is, there is no way for us to know.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no.  Usually you have to specify the address in your wallet and the threshold minimum so the pool sends your funds.

Most pools require some kind of registration; Eligius.St only requires your wallet's payment address.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can set up an auto transfer on many pools but you will need above a certain balance or be charged for transactions. Also some pools need verification for this to happen to prevent fraud or theft.